# How to generate private setters in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, setter

I am trying to create setters in IDEA for private member fields that I created in a Java class. I right click and select the generate option and it creates the setters.

The problem is that I want the setters to have a private access modifier and IDEA creates the setters with a public modifier.

Anyone know how to get IDEA to generate setters with the private modifier?

Comment: Why do you need private setters?

Comment: @PM_77-1 I am designing a library to wrap data received from a web api. Would you reccomend just setting the variable directly without a setter method from the class?

Comment: can you give us some screenshot of that generating tab in IDEA.

Comment: I figured it out. I was supposed to use the encapsulating menu, instead of the generate menu

Comment: A "private setter" is useless overkill.  Just set the variable directly.

Comment: You can also encapsulate multiple fields with private access modifier in one go. To do that, press Ctrl+Shift+a, type "encapsulate fields" in the openeing dialog select the fields you want and select private as Accessors Visiblity. Click ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [customize the getter template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDGhf.png) and [add one, and modify public to private](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYViT.png)